# Alternative to "mostly legacy" ref String Attribute?

Tags: reactjs

I was a bit surprised when I read the updated React [docs about refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html). While their examples on the React front page still use `this.refs.textarea`, they later "recommend" to not use this approach anymore.

But what's the alternative? I find too long inline code confusing and calling a function instead, like `{() => this.initChartLibrary() }` (the `() =>` is required to not lose context to `this`) requires to build a method that gives the wrong impression of that it can be reused.

In other words, I'd still like to use the String way. But since I fear they'll deprecate it, I was wondering, if there are any other approaches?

Comment: Could you please ellaborate on your use case with refs? As a sidenote, imho deprecating refs doesn't sound like something React would do, since it has usages you can't get with the regular props way (such as real DOM operations)

Comment: I have the exact same question. This is super confusing, especially to a React beginner such as me. Should I use it or should I not?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware the main alternative to `ref` strings is in fact the ES6 style callback function.

So:

```
<textarea ref="myTextArea">
...
</textarea>

// Where refs are then accessed by `this.refs.myTextArea` to perform any operations
```

Becomes, in a basic form:

```
<textarea ref={ (ref) => this.myTextArea = ref }>
...
</textarea>

// Where refs are then accessed by `this.myTextArea`
```

This can be pretty powerful because the `ref` attribute in React automatically receives the referenced component as a parameter, which allows us to immediately implement our callback operations on it if we'd like. This can be used in a simple form, as above, to assign that reference to `this.myTextArea`, or as you've probably noticed in the docs, you can be a bit more direct and do things like:

```
<input 
  ref = {(input) =>
          { if (input != null) {input.focus()} }
  } />
```

That being said, although this sometimes means you can express your code in the fewest number of lines, it definitely sacrifices readability. If you are just looking to save a reference to the component for use in an event handler (as is very commonly the case) using a `ref` string is honestly still the cleanest way to do so.

I really wouldn't anticipate them to be deprecated without warning, as they are used pretty heavily in React & remain convenient, but if they ever are your best bet would be a straightforward refactor with a simple `(ref) => this.myRef = ref` then accessing your refs by `this.myRef`.